# Install GitLab locally on solaris OS

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, solaris-10

I'm new with gitlab and I preferred it over github because it allows local installations on private servers, but the server that I want to install gitlab on it is not connected to internet, I can only FTP files to it. So my question is if I can find any ready gitlab package for solaris OS that I can move it to my solaris server after downloading it locally and install it on my solaris server?

Comment: I've not tested but you can follow [this](https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything) and [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/281810/how-to-install-packages-on-linux-or-solaris-on-non-default-paths).